# Can we have asynchronous behaviour without threads?

Tags: asynchronous

Discussions on asynchronous features of a program generally move towards things like Futures,Promises etc which in turn involves multi threaded environment.

Is it possible to write an asynchronous program without resorting to multiple threads?

Comment: you cant have async feature if you don't have multiple workers

Comment: It's possible to build a 100% async program that has only a single thread. Your language/platform may or may not choose to tie the two together, but async does not in general imply concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have async without multiple workers.

Even when you don't control them directly (Eg: such as NodeJS), they still exists on the background. So on those languages, you can use them without explicitly working with threads / forks.

Eg:

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile('example.txt',function(err,data){
    if(!err) {
     console.log(data);
    }
}); // 'fs.readFile' is async

console.log("something else"); // This will be executed right after the line above, and most likely the file ain't read yet.
```

Comment: As far as I understand, a js program is single threaded, but still it can support asynchronous tasks. Does it mean that multiple workers don't necessarily mean multiple threads?

Comment: Multiple workers means multiple threads / forks, you just can't control them.